# Why does clicking on the 'memory indicator' in PyCharm reduce the 'Used' heap size?

Tags: pycharm, heap-memory

How to reproduce:

1. Open a project in PyCharm.
2. Enable the memory indicator.

   1. In PyCharm, click File-->Settings.
   2. In the Settings window, click 'Appearance and Behavior'-->Appearance.
   3. Under 'Window Options', click the checkbox that says 'Show memory indicator'.
   4. Click 'OK'.
   5. The indicator should appear in the bottom-right corner of the editor.
3. Wait a minute or two and you should see the memory indicator indicate that PyCharm is using more memory.

   - Example: '67 of 676' --> '172 of 676'.
   - This may depend on the memory settings you have set up. In Help-->'Edit Custom VM Options', I have '-Xms' set to 128m and '-Xmx' set to 700m.
4. Click on the memory indicator.
5. You should see the number drop down to around where it started.

   - Example: '172 of 676' --> '80 of 676'.

I have looked online and can't find documentation for this feature.

Comment: I didn't know about the help-->'Edit Custom VM Options'. That's very useful to increase the memory allocation and enable pycharm to speed up if it is running slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because clicking on the icon triggers Java's [garbage collection](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/) (Idea platforms run on Java).